# What does FirstMatch mean in a EXPLAIN statement?

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

Today i noticed a "new" Extra type in a `EXPLAIN` of a statement.

This is my query

```
SELECT UrlId,'61','Australia' 
FROM dbase.phonenumbers
WHERE UrlId IN (SELECT UrlId FROM dbase.phonenumbers
                WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '+31%')
AND PhoneNumber LIKE '+61%'
```

And the EXPLAIN gives this,

```
phonenumbers    range   UrlId_PhoneNumber,PhoneNumber   PhoneNumber        12                               4176    Using where
phonenumbers    ref     UrlId_PhoneNumber,PhoneNumber   UrlId_PhoneNumber   4   dbase.phonenumbers.UrlId    4       Using where; Using index; FirstMatch(phonenumbers)
```

What does exactly `FirstMatch(phonenumbers)` mean? I never seen it before and couldnt find anything quick enough to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a strategy that avoids the production of duplicates by short-cutting execution as soon as the first genuine match is found.

So `FirstMatch(phonenumbers)` means that as soon as we have produced one matching record combination, it will short-cut the execution and jump back to the `phonenumbers` table.

From [FirstMatch strategy](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/firstmatch-strategy/)

> - The FirstMatch strategy works by executing the subquery and    short-cutting its execution as soon as the first match is found.
> - This means, subquery tables must be after all of the parent select's    tables that are referred from the subquery predicate.
> - EXPLAIN shows FirstMatch as "FirstMatch(tableN)".
> - The strategy can handle correlated subqueries.
> - But it cannot be applied if the subquery has meaningful GROUP BY    and/or aggregate functions.
> - Use of the FirstMatch strategy is controlled with the    firstmatch=on|off flag in the optimizer_switch variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That sounds optimal actually as i only need to find one or more. Could it have to do anything with the size of the table also as this has not been shown before when i ran `EXPLAIN` on same statement.

Comment: Thanks! So it can also be turned off, but why would you want that I wonder? I will accept the answer.